# change android layout height when click on it

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expand

I have a layout that contains several linear layouts. I want when click on child layout, change its height to match parent. I tried this code, but it does not expand layout when click on it:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
            null);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        View custom = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Custom View " + i);
        parent.addView(custom);
    }

    setContentView(parent);

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    final LinearLayout ro = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.row);
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ro.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
        }
    });
}
```

and activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

and row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using `ro.getLayoutParams().height = 100;` you are setting your view to be 100 pixels high. You should be using  `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` instead of 100. Additionally, you are setting your click listener on a view that is never actually added to your `parent` view. You are also trying to find a view by using a layout id.  `findViewById(R.layout.row)` will never resolve to a valid view id (maybe by luck). If your onClick was working you'd be getting a null pointer crash trying to access your view `ro`

Comment: please write a code for your solution. I tested your solution, but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
            null);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        View custom = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        custom.setTag(i); 
        TextView tv = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Custom View " + i);
        parent.addView(custom);
    }

    setContentView(parent);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      View row = findViewByTag(i);
       row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ro.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
           }
    });
    }        
}
```

Note: I have not tested it..plz resolve minor errors, if any